# SyntaxError: missing } after property list on Facebook generated code

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to run this generated by facebook code on my site, but it is not working. I'm getting error "SyntaxError: missing } after property list".
Code:

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/my-app-name-was-here:photo',
  'post',
  {
    og:url: http://samples.ogp.me/MYAPPIDWASHERE,
    og:title: Sample Photo,
    og:type: my-app-name-was-here:photo,
    og:image: https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png,
    og:description: ,
    fb:app_id: MYAPPIDWASHERE
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

What is wrong with this code? I got it from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP_ID_WAS_HERE/open-graph/object-types/

Answer (score 0):

the `API` you are trying to use here is

`FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {})`

In your code, the object part(the third argument), is not a valid object, and that's why the error. please provide a valid object here.

And by the way, the link you provided is broken

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/my-app-name-was-here:photo',
  'post',
  {
    url: 'http://samples.ogp.me/MYAPPIDWASHERE',
    title: 'Sample Photo',
    type: 'my-app-name-was-here:photo',
    image: 'https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png',
    description:'' ,
    app_id: 'MYAPPIDWASHERE'
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);
```

Facebook api third param should be an object. like {fields: 'value'}